# FullCalendar ignore timezone

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I already set;

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
            timezone:false,
            ignoreTimezone: true,...
```

So I expect it use current local time settings but its not.. when I select a time in calender event object date is 2 hours ahead.. I think its because my timezone is UTC+2 but I dont want it add anything I want whatever I select in calendar.. here  how it look..
(I select Monday 23:30 PM, but event date is: Tuesday 01:30 AM ) 
[image]

I see the browser that that object(Moment) has a property _isUTC:true.. I think this is my problem but how can I set it to false ?

Comment: timezone parameter should be false, check http://fullcalendar.io/docs/timezone/timezone/. There's a demo too: http://fullcalendar.io/js/fullcalendar-2.6.0/demos/timezones.html

Comment: I used it too, edit the post but change nothing still adding 2 hours to selected date

Comment: I edit the post.. not calendar but I think moment object uses UTC.. it look set true how can I edit it..

Comment: could you post the full code of calendar creation?

Comment: Use timezone:'local',

Comment: @ChintanMirani yes its done.. I can accept your answer if you want. Thank you

Comment: I posted answer. Thanks. Now other developer can get help from your question for same issue. and find solution with right answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can set local to timezone in your fullcalendar configuration.

```
timezone:'local',
```

It works!

Comment: Not sure when it changed, but it's now:  timeZone:'local' with an uppercase Z

Comment: My TOD is 09:00 but even with this it's reading 07:00... didn't work; big shock /s

Comment: How can disable it completely?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using "timezone: 'local'", sometime you may want to use "moment.local()" on an exact moment object to set its flag "isUTC" as false dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

I changed timeZone:'local' by timezone:'local' with a z lowerCase and it worked